# multiple markers at this line. - syntax error on token

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I have this code that will authenticate the user to input the password (the password is already defined by password). Now if the password is correct then he will go to the next process that is to add something on the database. process is already okay apart from this error. Thanks in advance. Hope you help me with this :(

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.ObjectStudent;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.DatabaseFragment;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.R;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.TableControllerStudent;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseFragment extends Fragment 
{
    public DatabaseFragment(){}

    Context thiscontext;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        thiscontext = container.getContext();
        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_database,
            container, false);
        Button buttonCreateLocation = (Button) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateStudent);
        buttonCreateLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View views) 
            {
                final Context context = views.getContext();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_input_form, null, false);

                final EditText usernamea = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                final EditText passworda = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.password);

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setView(formElementsView)
                    .setTitle("Login")
                    .setPositiveButton("Submit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                                {
                                    Editable password = null;
                                    if (passworda.getText()== password)
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) //THE ERROR IS LOCATED HERE
                                        {
                                            final Context context = view.getContext();

                                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                            View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_input_form, null, false);

                                            final EditText editTextStudentFirstname = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentFirstname);
                                            final EditText editTextStudentEmail = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentEmail);
                                            final EditText editTextStudentCategory = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentCategory);

                                            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                                .setView(formElementsView)
                                                .setTitle("Create Translation")
                                                .setPositiveButton("Add",
                                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                                                    {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                                                        {
                                                            String studentFirstname = editTextStudentFirstname.getText().toString();
                                                            String studentEmail = editTextStudentEmail.getText().toString();
                                                            String studentCategory = editTextStudentCategory.getText().toString();

                                                            ObjectStudent objectStudent = new ObjectStudent();
                                                            objectStudent.firstname = studentFirstname;
                                                            objectStudent.email = studentEmail;
                                                            objectStudent.category = studentCategory;

                                                            boolean createSuccessful = new TableControllerStudent(context).create(objectStudent);
                                                            if(createSuccessful)
                                                            {
                                                                Toast.makeText(context, "Student information was saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to save student information.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }

                                                            ((MainActivity) context).countRecords();
                                                            ((MainActivity) context).readRecords();

                                                            dialog.cancel();
                                                        }
                                                    }).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                }    
                        });
                return mRelativeLayout;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the database

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StudentDatabase";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE students " +
            "( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "firstname TEXT, " +
            "username TEXT, " +
            "password TEXT, " +
            "email TEXT, " 
            + "category TEXT ) ";

    db.execSQL(sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    onCreate(db);
}

 }
```

Comment: When posting code, don't post everything, only what's relevant.

Comment: where in this code the error shows up?

Comment: avoid nesting code so deep ... it's difficult to maintain.

Comment: What ^ they said, plus, this - `passworda.getText()== password` won't work.  Please read about Java `String` and `immutable`, then read the documentation for the `String.equals()` method, which you should use.  You have no control over whether `==` **may or may not be true** (read also about string interning to understand why).

Comment: The problem with this part
    `public void onClick(View view) //THE ERROR IS LOCATED HERE`
Is that you are trying to override a method in an if-statement instead of a class declaration. Which method in which class do you want to overwrite here?

Comment: am i going to declare a class there? actually starting from there was the real code. it just that my professor wants me to have an authentication to have a password to access the current fragment :( i really don't understand terminologies :( i just understand it when i look in to it :( yeah. m so dumb T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
multiple markers at this line
```

This Exception is thrown by SQLite Exception, you should post your database-filling code, aswell as the Logcat output ;)

Welcome by the way!

EDIT: You should aslo ALWAYS handle if-clauses with String-Types like this: `.equals("")` instead of: `==`

Comment: sir.i have already added the database part :( there's no logcat since there's an error there.

Comment: i also change the .equals("")